# Regex for password must be 6 to 8 characters long containing at least 3 alphabets, 2 number, no special character, Must not contain the sequence ‘pas’

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to write a regular expression to validate a password which must meet the following criteria:
a.  Password must be 6 to 8 characters long, contain at least 3 alpha and 2 numeric characters and no special characters.
b.  Must not contain the sequence ‘pas’.

What I've tried so far:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$/
```

Comment: What's the issue you have?

Comment: what did you try ? something... anything ?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself so far, this can be some code or your regular expression...

Comment: I am not able to create a regex for it. I have tried many solutions but not working fully.

Comment: At least show us your approaches you ve tried so far, that would be a good point to start helping you. Additionally i encourage you to checkout a regex website e.g. http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: Tried following :
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$/

Comment: What language are you using? Javascript I suppose?

Comment: That's not very good password criteria; I hope you're not using it for an important production system. Why a maximum of eight characters?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I am using Javascript.

Comment: @nnnnnn I am not using it for a production system.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to not use only one regex, because that way the users would not know why their password are failing.

I would do something like this:

```
function checkPassword (pass) {
    pass = {
        text: pass,
        length: pass.length,
        letters: pass.match(/[a-z]/gi).length,
        digits: pass.match(/[0-9]/g).length,
        contains_pas: !!pass.match(/pas/i)      // <- will result true/false
    }
    pass.specials = pass.length - pass.letters - pass.digits;
    // here you can use your logic
    // example:
    if (pass.contains_pas) {
        alert('The password can not contains "pas".');
    }
    return pass;    // you can return or not
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
([[a-zA-Z]{3,}+[0-9]{2}]*)^((?!pas).)*$

It works only if user enters consecutive alphabets and then numbers. So, its a partial solution to this problem.

For the stated problem, I would suggest not to use reg-ex. As, reg-ex validates a particular order, you should incorporate separate checks for each test.

Comment: yes, but it works only if user enters consecutive alphabets and then numbers. So, its a partial solution to this problem. Editing the answer also.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't... anything you put inside `[]` the character class will be treated as literal... Please, try [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/jN7kM8/1) to test your regular expressions